# how can create new array from multiple array in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, array-map

Two array given bellow , i want to first array first key and with second array second key and create new array.

```
 [animals1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Horse
            [1] => Dog1
            [1] => Cat
        )
[animals2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cow
            [1] => Dog2
            [1] => Rat
        )
```

i need array given bellow.

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Horse
            [1] => Cow
        ),
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dog1
            [1] => Dog2
        ),
[2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cat
            [1] => Rat
        )
```

Any Array related knowledge please share here ....

Comment: Loop one and join the two.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try using array_map() function.

```
$data['animalses'] = array_map(null, $animals1, $animals2);
```

Answer (score 0):

See Demo : [Live Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/db045)

let assumes that the keys in the initial arrays are unique and correspond to each other. If the keys are repeated, you may need to adjust the structure of your initial arrays to avoid ambiguity.

```
$array1 = array(
    'animals1' => array(
        'Horse',
        'Dog1',
        'Cat'
    ),
    'animals2' => array(
        'Cow',
        'Dog2',
        'Rat'
    )
);

$newArray = array();

foreach ($array1 as $key => $animals) {
    foreach ($animals as $index => $animal) {
        $newArray[$index][$key] = $animal;
    }
}

// Print the result
echo '<pre>'; print_r($newArray); echo '</pre>';
```